# Main difference between wx.lib.sheet and wx.Grid

Tags: python, wxpython

I need to develop a program that has a spreadsheetlike input interface. I found that some tutorials use `wx.Grid` widget and some use `wx.lib.sheet`. What is the main difference between those two methods?

[`wx.lib.sheet` tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#SpreadSheet)

[`wx.grid` tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-an-introduction-to-grids/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wx.lib.sheet.CSheet` [extends](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/wx/lib/sheet.py#L167) `wx.grid.Grid` class and provides few additional helpful methods like `Copy`, `Paste` (copy and paste cell(s)). Plus, it has customized CellEditor, which behaves more like your excel spreadsheet in terms of mouse clicking, keyboard events.

So, if I were you, I'd go with `CSheet`.

Comment: Well I do not need full spreadsheet experience and I find wx.grid sufficient for my needs so far, anyway thank You for explanation!

Comment: Yeah, there are not so many differences, so you can easily switch if you want. You're welcome.